# Exception thrown at 0x7B639D4E (ucrtbased.dll) in Project48.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
struct Employee
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char position[20];
    int salary;
    int dateofjoin;
    char address[20];
};

int main()
{
    struct Employee a[5], b[5];
    FILE* fptr;
    int i;
    fptr = fopen("file.txt", "wb");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEnter ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].id);
        printf("\nEnter name: ");
        scanf("%s",&a[i].name);
        printf("\nEnter Position/Designation: ");
        scanf("%s",&a[i].position);
        printf("\nEnter Salary: ");
        scanf("%d", a[i].salary);
        printf("\nEnter DateOfJoining: ");
        scanf("%d", a[i].dateofjoin);
        printf("Enter Address: ");
        scanf("%s",&a[i].address);
    }
    fwrite(a, sizeof(a), 1, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    fptr = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
    fread(b, sizeof(b), 1, fptr);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("\nID: %d \tName: %s \tPosition/Designation: %s Salary: %d\tDateOfJoining: %d\tAddress: %s", b[i].id, b[i].name, b[i].position, b[i].salary, b[i].dateofjoin,
            b[i].address);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

My program always crash after giving salary input, I even tried #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS, to avoid error but it is of no use. hope I'll get my problem solved soon, please do explain when you reply as it is sort of assignment for me

Comment: OT: but errorchecking after `fopen` is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `scanf("%d", a[i].salary);` & is missing before `a[i].salary`

Comment: ... and also before `a[i].dateofjoin`